# How do use app-scripts to paste down a formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

Right now I'm able to paste the formula from row X to row Y, however, the calculations in the formulas are the exact same. Say row 1 is A1+B1, the formula for row 5 should be A5+B5, but I'm still getting A1+B1.

```
for (var x = col; x < lastCol; x++) {
    for (var j = 2; j <= lastRow; j++) {
      var range = sheet.getRange(j,x);

      range.setFormula(formulas[0][i]);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Should I be using another function instead of setFormula or doing something else? I'm iterating over X amount of columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use new method [`autoFillToNeighbor`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#autofilltoneighborseries) introduced in **October, 2017**.

For example if you have three columns **with just one formula** in cell `C2`:

[image]

then you can autofill rest of `C` column just with one line of code:

```
function doTheMagic() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C2").autoFillToNeighbor(SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
}
```

**Result**:

[image]